# comm -23 not deleting all common lines

Tags: duplicates, comm

I want to delete lines from file 1.txt that are in file 2.txt and save the output to 3.txt,
I am using this bash command:

```
comm -23 1.txt 2.txt > 3.txt
```

When I check the output in file 3.txt, I find that some common lines between 1.txt and 2.txt are still in 3.txt, take as an example the word "registry" , what is the problem?

You can download the two files below:

file 1.txt : https://ufile.io/n7vn6

file 2.txt : https://ufile.io/p4s58

Comment: I haven't checked your files but I am guessing you didn't sort them before using `comm`.

Comment: Is there extra whitespace you're not taking into account?

Comment: they are sorted, and there is no extract space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you generated your text files, but the problem is that some of your `1.txt` and `2.txt` lines don't have consistent line terminations. Some have a CR character (ctrl-M) but not the sole line feed Linux expects for text files. For example, one of them has `registry^M` which doesn't match `registry` (Linux programs that examine text will see `^M` as another character or white space but not as a line termination that gets ignored). When you look at the file with some text editors, the `^M` isn't visible so it appears `registry` is the same in both places, but it isn't.

You could try:

```
dos2unix 1.txt 2.txt
comm -23 <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt) > 3.txt
```

`dos2unix` will make all of the line terminations correct (assuming they might be using the DOS CR). Note that this can affect the sort a little, so I'm also resorting them. You can try this without resorting, and if there's an issue `comm` will give an error that one of the files isn't sorted.

Comment: well, it would change the input files.

Comment: All I need is the alphabetic characters,  what would I do with those hidden characters related to some bizzare encoding  :D

Comment: @hek2mgl that may be a good thing if the contents need fixing. Unclear what the overall use case is. The OP can choose other means of addressing the issue if needed now that they know the problem.

Comment: @Youcef it's not about _alphabetic_ characters. This solution doesn't change the encoding, just the line endings.

Comment: I am using those files for NLP tasks, I guess it's not necessary to keep the original encoding since the meaning and visual of the word is still the same

Comment: @lurker If the content needs fixing, then the producer of the data has to be fixed. Unless that has been identified to be the problem, it is fair to assume that the Windows line endings are in place for a reason. And since there is no reason to change the input files in place for the comparison, I would just not recommend to do it.

Comment: @Youcef sure, that's fine.

Comment: I don't know, the file that has special encoding was downloaded from github project for google n-gram dataset, here is the link https://github.com/first20hours/google-10000-english

Comment: That's a good example actually. If you cloned those files from git and change them in place, you'll have to reset those files again before you can pull a new version from upstream. Not a big deal, sure (depending on the situation). But why bother?

Answer (score 2):

`comm` needs the input to be sorted. You can use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) for that:

```
comm -23 <(sort 1.txt) <(sort 2.txt) > 3.txt
```

Update, if you additionally have a problem with line endings, you can use `sed` to align that:

```
comm -23 <(sed 's/\r//g' 1.txt | sort) <(sed 's/\r//g' 2.txt| sort) > 3.txt
```